# Alphanumeric Ranges UI

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-interface

I've got an application which i want users to be able to enter alphanumeric ranges into for various reasons.

The user would enter in the first alphanumeric value and then i would increase this by 1 for every entry added to the system.

Examples of ranges:

TGH001 
TGH002
TCH003

BCV00A
BCV00B
BCV00C

But also i want them to lock numbers/letters for example

BCV01A
BCV02A
BCV03A

Programming this being the scene is quiet easy once you know what letters are lock etc.

My problem is i can’t come up with a UI system of this looking good and easy to use.

I don’t really want to create a missive wizard for the user to do, more just a single text box or something.

Any one got any good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why steal some ideas from excel and `String.Format`

If a letter is locked, prefix it with a special character. eg `$`
If it should be incremented use a different character or wrap it with special characters. eg `{}`

eg

```
$T$G$H{001} 
$T$G$H{002} 
$T$G$H{003} 

$B$C$V{01}$A
$B$C$V{02}$A
$B$C$V{03}$A
```

Or even simpler, just wrap the bit that needs to increment:

```
BCV{01}A
BCV{02}A
BCV{03}A
```

Modify to whatever scheme suits your needs/users best.

Comment: Thanks, ive gone for this since the clients are keen on excel

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be a question mark. Just let the user enter the mask as he likes in a simple TextBox like this:

```
TGH???
BCV??A
```

This sign is commonly known as placeholder. Just put some label (or something alike) above (or near) the entry box to provide the user with some informations (and maybe examples) on how to enter is mask.

Additionally if you are forced to six letters you could also allow something like this

```
TGH
```

which would mean that you would fill up the places not used (by six letters) automatically with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with GUI and SILVERLIGHT, how about adding in some graphical elements?

Maybe letting the user turn on/off arrows/triangles on the numbers to use with the click of a mouse. (Simple illustration below)

```
   ^^^      ^^         ^
TGH001   BVC00A   BCV00A
   vvv      vv         v
```

...or drawing a frame around some of the characters, or different colors/backgrounds etc.